# Add SQL strings in a Query

Tags: android, mysql, delphi

I have this code in Delphi 10.2 and runs in android.
The data are in a remote mysql server.

```
Query1.SQL.Text := '';
Query1.SQL.Add('SELECT userid, userphoto, username');
Query1.SQL.Add('FROM users');
Query1.SQL.Add('WHERE usermail = ' + #39 + Text1.Text + #39);
Query1.Execute;
```

The problem is the SQL in the Query added like this

```
SELECT userid, userphoto, username
FROM users
WHERE usermail = 'THE TEXT
'
```

That SQL gives back an empty field. 
Why the last character goes to a new line?
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Debug this code and see if there is an embedded newline character in Text1.Text

Comment: Unrelated, but instead of concatenating your where clause like that, I would strongly suggest using a parameter. The current code is susceptible to SQL injection.

Comment: If you don't use a parameterized query (which you should!), then at least use `QuotedStr()` instead of manual quoting: `Query1.SQL.Add('WHERE usermail = ' + QuotedStr(Text1.Text));`  That will prevent SQL Injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of component is `Text1`? Does it accept line feeds? It looks like accessing `Text1.Text` is returning `'THE TEXT'#10`.

Try to check if the last character is `#10` (or possibly `#13` or the last two characters are `#13#10`) and remove them.

And do what Bruce McGee says: Use a query with a parameter. We don't need yet another app that is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: You could just `Trim()` the string.  However, if `Text1` really does allow multi-line input, then there could be line breaks in the middle of the `Text` as well, so looking at just the first/last characters is not enough. You might need to use `StringReplace()` instead.  Or, just don't use a multi-line input control to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Query` function `Parameters.ParamByName`.

Create a parameter with name `:email` in SQL Query, then assign `string` value like:

```
Query1.SQL.Clear;
Query1.SQL.Text('SELECT userid, userphoto, username From users where useremail = :email');
Query1.SQL.ParamByName('useremail').Value := 'THE TEXT';
```